Keeping track of the expanded sub menu in Shiny Dashboard
I just recently learned that once you go from a childless menuitem to a childful menuitem, you need to use input$sidebarItemExpanded, to keep track of which menu is expanded. This works very well, however it does not work for my childful submenus.
Should it work, or is there another approach for tracking which submenu is expanded?
Reproducible code:
ui <- function(){
  shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
    shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(title = "title1"),
    sidebar = shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
      shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
        id = "sidebarItemSelected",
        shinydashboard::menuItem(
          "Scores",
          expandedName = "Scores",
          startExpanded = TRUE,
          selected = TRUE, 
          dateRangeInput("dateRange", "Select Date Range",
                         start = as.Date("2023-01-24"), 
                         end = Sys.Date(),  
                         format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),
          uiOutput("scoreCheckboxes"),
          fluidRow(downloadButton("downloadData", "Journalisering", class = 'button', style = "width:60%;")),
          br(),
          fluidRow(downloadButton("downloadData_sensitive_removed", "Aktindsigt", class = 'button', style = "width:60%;")),
          tags$head(
            tags$style(
              ".button{background-color:black;} .button{color: white;} .button{font-style: bold;} .button{margin-left:55px;}"
            ))),
        shinydashboard::menuItem("name1", expandedName = "name1", startExpanded = FALSE, selected = FALSE, 
                                 fileInput("upload1", "Upload 1", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                 fileInput("upload2", "Upload 2", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                 fileInput("upload3", "Upload 3", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                 fileInput("upload4", "Upload 4", accept = c(".xlsx")),
                                 fileInput("upload5", "Upload 5", accept = c(".xlsx"))
        ),
        shinydashboard::menuItem("name2", expandedName = "name2", startExpanded = FALSE,
                                 shinydashboard::menuItem("name3", expandedName = "name3", startExpanded = FALSE,
                                                          textInput("newname", "Indtast nyt navn"),
                                                          actionButton("addP", "Tilføj ", class = "btn-primary"),
                                                          actionButton("removeP", "Fjern ", class = "btn-danger"),
                                                          actionButton("uploadP", "Opdater ", class = "btn-primary")
                                 ),
                                 shinydashboard::menuItem("name4", expandedName = "name4", startExpanded = FALSE,
                                                          actionButton("setThresholds", "Set værdi", class = "btn-primary")
                                 )
        )
      )
    ),
    
    body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
      shinydashboard::tabItem("ML",
                              verbatimTextOutput("outtext"),
                              DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, {
    print(paste("Sidebar item expanded:", input$sidebarItemExpanded))
    print(paste("Sidebar item selected:", input$sidebarItemSelected))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui(), server = server)

EDIT: If i open 'name2' and then open one of the submenus 'name3' or 'name4' and then close 'name2', the name of that submenu will be printed so it has updated input$sidebaritemexpanded. But obviously this is not a fix, but rather a sign that this is not working as intended, since any user would never close the parent menu to render the child's content.


Red menu items update "sidebarItemExpanded", orange (submenus to red3) does not.


Please provide us with a full reproducible example.

@ismirsehregal I added a reproducible example to the post
